# Do any n linearly independent vectors span $R^n$? If yes, what's the proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

This question comes from working exercises where n vectors are given and we need to show they are a basis of $R^n$
I know that for them to be a basis they need to be linearly independent and span $R^n$ but all the solutions involve only showing they are linear independent, does this imply they span the vector space as well?
If yes, is there any thing to show it as intuitively I can't see why this would work.

Comment: If $m$ vectors are linearly independent, then they span an $m$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Can you show me the proof for that?

Comment: Consider vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$. If $\dim \text{Span}\{v_1,\ldots v_m\}<m$, then some vector, say $v_j$ is dependent to the others.